# Cannot run sails on Pivotal Web Services

Tags: node.js, sails.js, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

So I tried to load a super simple demo with blank sails template using this

https://github.com/danielkennedy/sailsjs-demo

```
$ sudo npm install sails -g
$ sails new sailsjs-demo
$ cd sailsjs-demo
```

Modified `config/local.js`:

```
port: process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 1337
```

If I do `cf push -c "sails lift" -m 150M my-sailsdemo` and go to `my-sailsdemo.cfapps.io` or `my-sailsdemo.cfapps.io:1337` from the browser, there is nothing and the browser kept spinning.

Then I visited this site

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

and changed command line to

```
cf push -c "sails lift" -m 150M -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-nodejs.git my-sailsdemo
```

It is still the same issue.

Although the app is running just fine.

I am assuming either node.js or sails.js did not load right. What did I miss?

Comment: Probably the order of the parameters in the command, try this order: `cf push my-app -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack"`

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, in the command area, try `node app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I missed creating manifest.xml file. I thought it was optional. Basic mistake.